# CRM 2011: Reauthentication with _serviceProxy.Authenticate()

Tags: wcf, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, wcf-security

I have developed a client software for ms dynamics 2011 using WCF channel and organization service. After creating the channel I put it into dictionary `Dictionary<string, OrganizationServiceProxy>` and after 8 hours waiting was over, the security token was not valid any more. Now I call `serviceProxy.Authenticate()` method (serviceProxy is an object retrieved from my collection) and nothing happens. My token has not been renewed and I can not use my channel to retrieve data from dynamics. As I read in msdn, `Authenticate()` method should deliver me a new token, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to monitor the token like described in [Performance Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509027#Performance)?

> In addition, monitor your WCF security token (Token) and refresh it before it expires so that you do not lose the token and have to start over with authentication. To check the token, create a custom class that inherits from the OrganizationServiceProxy or DiscoveryServiceProxy class and that implements the business logic to check the token. Or wrap the proxy classes in a new class. Another technique is to explicitly check the token before each call to the web service. *Example code that demonstrates these techniques can be found in the ManagedTokenDiscoveryServiceProxy, ManagedTokenOrganizationServiceProxy, and AutoRefreshSecurityToken classes in the Helper Code: [ServerConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309393) Class topic.*

You will find an example of how you could automatically renew the token in this classes.

Comment: Thanks, now i'am one step forward. Now i know, that I schould call .Autheticate() method BEFORE token expires. But also in this case the token will not be renewd. Schuold I do the renewing not earlier then 15 minutes before token expires (like it has been shown above in your example with helper code)? Or is there any another reason, why the token doesn renew?

Comment: @lgor Hello, have you found out why the token is not renewing? I got same issue here. I wrote a unit test that check the new expiry date is greater than the old expiry date after calling authenticate() method but it turns out the expiry dates are same.