# Microsoft Dynamics CRM online - renew token

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have a long running application that needs to load a huge amount of data into CRM and it is going to take a long time to run.

I found that the token created from authentication only last for 8 hours so I am looking for a solution to renew it when the expiry time is approaching. I found a few articles on internet advising using the Authenticate() method in the OrganizationServiceProxy object.

For example:

1. https://blog.thomasfaulkner.nz/post/2015/03/crm-organization-service-(re)authentication
2. There is also one on StackOverflow. [CRM 2011: Reauthentication with _serviceProxy.Authenticate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258908/crm-2011-reauthentication-with-serviceproxy-authenticate)

So I wrote a unit test to check if it is working as expected. However, the result turns out to be that the token is not renewed.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe split the data load into batches and authenticate every X hours with a new instance of the Org Service every time??

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah, I have done a similar thing. Instead of calling the Authenticate() method in the proxy object, I make it to go through the entire authentication process again to get a new token. Just don't know why people say the Authenticate() method should work but it doesn't in fact.